# Rails looking for MySQL instead of Postgres after MYSql installation

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I was using postgresql with rails. I installed mysql yesterday for some side project and today when I ran `rails c`, It gave the following error,

```
home/rahul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/arel-9.0.0/lib/arel/visitors.rb:7:in require': cannot load such file -- arel/visitors/mysql (LoadError)
```

I have not changed anything in my rails project. My rails application still uses Postgres

**database.yml**

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  pool: 50
  timeout: 5000
  # host: localhost
  encoding: utf8
development:
  <<: *default
  database: enquiry_dispatch_development
test:
  <<: *default
  database: enquiry_dispatch_test
```

Comment: How does your `config/database.yml` look like (without password!)? Did you replace `pg` with `mysql2` in your `Gemfile` and run `bundle install`?

Comment: @spickermann, I have put my database.yml in question. And no, my Gemfile contains pg and not mysql2

Comment: please check in application if somewhere is written require 'mysql' or 'mysql2'

Comment: No. As I said earlier, my rails application used postgresql from the beginning and nothing has been changed in it.

Answer (score 3):

Hello just remove the gem 'arel'

```
gem uninstall arel
```

and run

```
bundle install
```